# How to install Python 2.7 with Unix libraries on Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, make, ncurses

How do I install Python 2.7 with Unix libraries on Cygwin?

Obviously getting Python 2.6 is easy - just install the Cygwin package with `setup.exe`.

Installing the Windows version of Python 2.7 was also easy, but I could not access the [Unix modules](http://docs.python.org/library/unix.html).

So I've been trying to install Python from source, but it seems every time I fix one [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) error there is another waiting just behind it. I am getting rather fed up with the whole thing and thinking someone else must have either done this or figured out it is impossible.

I feel installing Linux would have been the easier route...

I have been trying for about a week to get this to work.

Comment: I assume all the trouble you're hitting is the reason why Cygwin hasn't moved to using Python 2.7 by default.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe following this guide will be enough for what you need: http://web.archive.org/web/20160409142417/http://www.tux.org/~mayer/cygwin/python/index.html

> 1. Download the desired version from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/. Here are the direct links:
>      [Python-2.7.1.tar.bz2](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tar.bz2), [Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2), or [Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2).
> 2. Download the matching patch [Python-2.7.1-cygwin.patch.bz2](http://www.tux.org/~mayer/cygwin/python/Python-2.7.1-cygwin.patch.bz2), [Python-2.7.2-cygwin.patch.bz2](http://www.tux.org/~mayer/cygwin/python/Python-2.7.2-cygwin.patch.bz2), or [Python-2.7.3-cygwin.patch.bz2](http://www.tux.org/~mayer/cygwin/python/Python-2.7.3-cygwin.patch.bz2).
> 3. Unpack the sources, for example for 2.7.3:
>    `tar -jxvf Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2`
> 4. Patch the sources, for example for 2.7.3:
>     `bzcat Python-2.7.3-cygwin.patch.bz2 | patch -p0`
> 5. Configure the build. For example, you may want to install into `/usr/local`:
>     `cd Python-2.7.3`
>    `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`
> 6. Compile the configured sources:
>    `make`
> 7. Install the compiled build:
>     `make install`